# Bool tool - apply change only when certain operation is finished

Tags: boolean-modifier

Whenever I use bool tool operations and want to move/scale the cutting object or change it in edit mode the boolean is calculated at every mouse move, at every action. Is it possible to calculate the new boolean after I moved/scaled someting?

I usually work with complex models and it is literally impossible to work with booleans like that.

Thanks.

Comment: You can temporarily turn off its effect on the modifier panel by clicking the monitor icon but I doubt there's any other way.

Comment: You can disable displaying the modifier in the viewport and specifically in edit mode. Disabling it also disables the recalculations.

Comment: Yes I'm doing that, but turning it off means another 2 minutes of computing time. I see no reason why it needs to recalculate all the time. But I'm a simple man, I might be wrong.

Comment: I don't know how complex your meshes are that it takes 2 minutes of computing time... on simpler geometry where it's computed quicker, some people actually find it useful that it's realtime calculated on the fly, as they can then sometimes change the size of a cutting object while seeing the result until they visually like how it turns out.